# Correct value of the user input is not getting inserted into the stack

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

So, I wrote a program to insert a user input to a stack myself. But despite my rigorous trying, I could not insert the data correctly. It show data has been inserted, but while showing, garbage value is shown. Here is my main function:

```
//Stack
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAXSTK 10

void push(int *, int, int *, int);
//void pop();
void show_stack();
int main()
{  
int ch, ch1, stack[MAXSTK], top=-1;
do{ 
    printf("\n <<Stack MENU>>");
printf("1. Add Element");
printf("2. Delete Element");
printf("3. Show Stack");
printf("4. Exit menu");
printf("\n Enter your choice->");
scanf("%d", &ch);

    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1: printf("\n Enter element to add->");
            scanf("%d",&ch1);
            push(stack,ch1, &top, MAXSTK);
            break;
          /*   case 2:      pop();
            break;*/
        case 3: printf("\n The stack is->");
            show_stack(stack, MAXSTK);
            break;
        default: printf("\n Invalid Choice!!!");
            break;
       }
 }while(ch!=4);
return 0;
   }
```

And here is my push function:

```
void push(int newstack[], int num, int *newtop, int bound)
 {
 *newtop=*newtop+1;
if(*newtop==0)
printf("\n Stack was Empty. New Value inserted.");

if(*newtop>(bound-1))
{
    printf("\n Caution! OVERFLOW!!!");

}
newstack[*newtop]=num;
}
```

And here is my show function:

```
void show_stack(int newstack[], int bound)
{
int i;
printf("\n");
for(i=0;i<=bound;i++)
printf("%d",newstack[i]);
 }
```

Please help me finding the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing the array length and printing all array elements. so you see garbage value. Try to print only the inserted elements.

```
 show_stack(stack, top);
```

and your function prototype should be

```
void show_stack(int *,int);
```

you increment your newtop everytime regardless of overflow. it's a bad practice. It will cause issues while popping() and show_stack().
you can do something like this to avoid it.

```
void push(int newstack[], int num, int *newtop, int bound)
{
    // if newtop is < 0 display the message
    if(*newtop<0)
       printf("\n Stack was Empty. New Value inserted.");
    // newtop will always point to top element. so if newtop is 9 it means your stack is full. so if newtop is >= bound-1(9) stack is full
    if(*newtop>=(bound-1))
       printf("\n Caution! OVERFLOW!!!");
    else
    {
      *newtop=*newtop+1; //increment newtop
      newstack[*newtop]=num; //store value in newtop
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant explanation.Thank you for also pointing the logical error in the push function. The error you mentioned was messing with my stack as well; I caught it during show. +1

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `show_stack` with the capacity (`MAXSTK`), not its actual size. Therefore it will display all elements in `stack`, whatever values they have. Simply calling it with `top` instead should fix the problem.

Another note: Your declaration of `show_stack` does not match the argument list of the implementation.